# How to identify this .NET syntax

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on an old application and these files seem to have been made 12+ years ago. This is a .NET application. The files I'm looking at are .st files and I believe the previous developers referred to them as string template files. They appear to be used as an MVC 5.2.3 view.

Every time I see MVC views referenced it's with .cshtml files. These look very different from .cshtml files. They are rendering HTML files that have logic to determine what to display. It's mostly readable but there are functions like *strip* or *rest* that I'm not familiar with. I just need to find out how to further research this stuff so I know how to recreate it with the new framework and get rid of it. I'll include a snippet of the .st file.

```
<input id="unique-id" type="hidden" value="$model.UniqueId$" name="uniqueId" />
<input id="id" type="hidden" value="$model.Id$" name="form.Id" />
<input id="version" type="hidden" name="form.Version" value="$model.Version; format="0"$" />
<input id="this-type" type="hidden" value="$model.ItemType.Value$" />
<input type="hidden" name="form.CurrencyConversionFactor" value="$model.CurrencyConversionFactor$" $disabled$ />
```

I've tried researching on Google and asking Chat GPT many many questions with no conclusive results. Chat GPT keeps leaning towards an older language called Smalltalk and I don't think that's what I'm dealing with here. Everything it does seems to be working correctly, I just need to understand it. The example above is pretty straight forward. The names/values are given variables from a ViewModel.

### Update

Found documentation!

https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ST/pages/1409038/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet

Comment: I looked at "$ sign template mvc" and came up with this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/advanced/custom-mvc-templates . it may be of use.

Comment: ...I have a horrible sinking-feeling that whoever wrote that is just doing `String.Replace` calls over-and-over and then serving it...

Comment: OP, I assume these files are in source-control and you can view their history? Can you glean anything from there? Do you see any references to `ViewEngine` in the codebase - or otherwise see where `UniqueId` (for example) gets its value from originally? Are you able to run this code as-is right now? If so, can you trace execution with the step-through debugger?

Comment: @Sean This actually looks promising! Everything in this application is custom built. I would not be surprised if everything is completely custom.

Comment: @Dai There are references to ViewEngine. Looks like in almost if not all of the controllers. The UniqueId is something I'm familiar with. It's a value stored in the database. And yes, the code runs fine as -is. I'm updating the entire application and just want to replace it. I can't put breakpoints in these files and breakpoints in associated C# files have not revealed anything useful.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `get` accessor of that `UniqueId` property and see where the debugger pauses whenever that property is read - the debugger might break ("break" as in pause-for-debugging, not break as-in "stop-working") a few times, but hopefully eventually you'll see where/how it reads from that property such that it ends-up in the rendered HTML.

Comment: @Dai I can't thank you enough. I finally found it. About to edit the post with more info. But I somehow have never noticed the "Show External Code" button in Visual Studio. I finally have documentation to reference!

Answer (score 0):

This is not .NET syntax at all - this is something SOMEONE came up with to do replaceable strings in an XML file. Basically, AN APP (that can be written in anything) looks for those monikers to replace them.

It is definitely not Smalltalk. This type of stuff is quite standard - you want something easy to identify, so you add markers at the beginning and end and do a simple replacement.